# How to download an S3 object using awless?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Given that the credentials are present in ~/.aws/credentials and region is set in ~/.aws/config, how can I download an S3 object via S3 URI using `awless` tool?

Comment: First up, try reading the documentation ( https://github.com/wallix/awless ). If that doesn't work, try Google. Once you've tried something, if it doesn't work, please edit your question to tell us what you tried and exactly what happened.

Comment: There's sync command but unfortunately it doesn't seem to sync s3 storage objects. Nevertheless, it doesn't tell how to fetch just 1 single object

Comment: Have you considered using the AWS S3 tool? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for an analogue of `aws s3 cp`. AWS itself is rather bloated required python, while awless has lean binary.

Comment: S3 has a rest interface - it's it's a giant web server. Have you considered using that rather than awless or the aws s3 tool?

Comment: Yes, ended up doing exactly that (curl+openssl). Still, I would like to have the whole aws toolset at the disposal and not be required to reimplement whatever little thing I might need from aws. Awlses seems to be the perfect lean tool for that, but still looking for a way to sync single object.

Comment: Worth mentioning that aws-cli tool times out if your file takes longer than 60s to download.